# Using cartopy to project geostationary data points onto a regular grid

Tags: python, gis, cartopy, satellite-image

I'm trying to use Cartopy to project GOES satellite imagery data onto a regular grid across the USA. I'm doing something wrong with my translation from GOES to grid at the end of
[this colab workbook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1G0al22FkEYCFWHzVQtduxcx2W64KFPnK). I'm doing this:

```
geos.transform_point(us_bbox[0][0] + x, us_bbox[0][1] + y, ccrs.PlateCarree()) / sat_h
```

As you can see from the image at the end, it isn't projecting onto the grid and is getting distorted somehow.

Edit: here's a bit more of the code from [the colab workbook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1G0al22FkEYCFWHzVQtduxcx2W64KFPnK):

```
grid_width = 500
grid_height = 500
grid = np.zeros((grid_width, grid_height))

for x in range(0, grid_width):
  for y in range(0, grid_height):
    location_geos = geos.transform_point(us_bbox[0][0] + x, us_bbox[0][1] + y, ccrs.PlateCarree()) / sat_h
    if not np.any(np.isnan(location_geos)):
      grid[(x, y)] = C['BCM'].sel(y=location_geos[1],x=location_geos[0],method='nearest').values
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: please post relevant code in question.  Use of web links or images is not encouraged.

Comment: It felt like it was too much code to include, but I've edited to add a bit more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably a really silly question, as I don't know the libraries in question, but in the line

```
location_geos = geos.transform_point(us_bbox[0][0] + x, us_bbox[0][1] + y, ccrs.PlateCarree()) / sat_h
```

are you adding latitude/longitude (`us_bbox` values) to integers (`x, y`)? If so your final plotted image has a range of 500 degrees latitude/longitude and, actually, this might make sense of the image.

Comment: That was it, thank you so much! Sometimes you just need another set of eyes.